# How do i extend the Bluemix PHP runtime with specific libraries

Tags: php, mongodb, ibm-cloud

I am using the PHP runtime on Bluemix and I need to access a MongoDB. For that I want to use a Mongo library. Normally you install your own extensions and add `extension=mongo.so`to the `php.ini`.
Since you cannot SSH the runtime, you need to do it otherwise.
How can I arrange this in the runtime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually do not need to edit `php.ini`.

You can install extensions with the PHP buildpack.  You need to create a file called `options.json` in a folder called `.bp-config`. The full path would be `.bp-config/options.json`.

The file would need to look like the following.

```
{
  "PHP_EXTENSIONS": ["mongo", "php_mongo"]
}
```

Mongo then gets installed, I have copied my `phpinfo` output for Mongo below.
[image: mongo]

Comment: mmm I am still getting this error: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'MongoClient' not found in /home/vcap/app/htdocs/send_file_wic.php on line 7\n

Comment: The complete answer is here: https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/13338/php-and-mongo-deploy-bluemix-issue.html